# how to add pop up messages to a document in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

i want to write a macro or add-in in visual studio which will pop up a message above some words in the active document, just cant find the way. plz :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm torn on whether or not to vote to close this as a duplicate, but you didn't specify the Visual Studio version.  If 2010, it's been covered and [this may help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213103/writing-visual-studio-2010-plugin-would-like-to-show-a-toolbox-like-resharper-in).  If 2008 (and I think the same was true for 2005, and the documentation goes back to 2003 as well), there seems to be a [good bit of documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esk3eey8(v=VS.90).aspx).

Comment: yea looks like those links will do, i just didnt know the right words to search :D